# Intercept docker container https requests traffic with mitmproxy

Tags: security, docker, https, mitmproxy

How can I configure [docker](https://www.docker.com) with [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org)? I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272002/running-docker-container-through-mitmproxy), but being beginner in docker and mitmproxy it is difficult to understand it.
I know that the mitmporxy doc. contains tutorial, to [transparently proxify VM](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/tutorials/transparent-dhcp.html), but how to do it with docker container? Links that I have found, but have no idea if they are any help for me: [link1](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/#troubleshooting-tips), [link2](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/certinstall.html)

I have installed the mitmproxy on my machine(in the post I referred to the mitmproxy was run in docker container). *(Background: I want to use mitmproxy with Integration tests in Magento devbox that is docker container. I want to run mitmproxy stream.py example to stream docker container responses. )* Sorry, I know the question is quite broad, but I do not know any place else, where I can get some help.